# Forcing trailing slash at end of "fake" folders

Tags: htaccess, apache, url-rewriting, trailing-slash

The working codes that I've found here most put a slash in everything.

I just need force trailing slash in these "fake dirs" (that are part of my rewriting scheme (only directories)) and keep everything else (fake files ending with `.html`) as it is.

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php?category=1

Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?p=$1&opc=4
RewriteRule ^album/$ /index.php?p=1&opc=4

RewriteRule ^album/(.*)-(.*).html /view.php?id=$2&lang=$1

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/$ /index.php?lang=en&search=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^channels/(.*)/$ /index.php?lang=en&channel=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/favorites/$ /index.php?lang=en&favorites=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/likes/$ /index.php?lang=en&likes=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/albums/(.*)/$ /index.php?lang=en&albumid=$2|$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/albums/$ /index.php?lang=en&album=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^albums/$ /index.php?lang=en&album=all  [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^newest/$ /index.php?opc=1&lang=en  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^popular/$ /index.php?opc=2&lang=en  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^best/$ /index.php?opc=3&lang=en  [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^categories/$ /index.php?category=1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?p=$1&category=1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^categories/(.*)/$ /index.php?lang=en&categories=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^categories/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?lang=en&categories=$1&p=$2  [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What is a "fake" folder?  What is the difference between a fake folder and a real folder to you?

Comment: "most put a slash in everything." - What do you mean by this? None of the directives you've posted above "put a slash in _anything_"? However, most of these directives are _expecting_ a trailing slash at the end of the requested URL - is that what you are referring to? But, how are you wanting to "force" this? With a redirect? Or simply allow access to the URL with and without the trailing slash?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I mean by "fake folder"  a dynamic folder... the file and folder doesn`t exist on server.....

Comment: @MrWhite The script generates pretty urls with folders and `.html`, (yes pretty urls with `.html`) but when you try to access this folder without trailing slashs, ( sample: `www.sample.com/folder` ) it shows a 404 page, it only works with  `/` at the end..... I am try to force these folders with trailing-slash at the end with some kind htaccess redir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to redirect to add the slash.  This will redirect any set of letters without other punctuation such as slashes or dots in them.   I don't think it conflicts with any of your other rewrite rules.

```
RewriteRule ^((.*/)?[a-z]+)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

You could make it a bit safer by making sure it doesn't match existing files on disk.  To do so prepend these two conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Alternately, you could put in separate rules for each of your "fake" directories:

```
RewriteRule ^(album|categories|newest|best)$  /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^((search|categories)/[^/]+)$  /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/(favorites|likes|albums))$  /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/albums/[^/]+)$  /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

'Fake folders', or 'permalinks', are often used by Wordpress.  You set these up from your WP back end in Settings->Permalinks, where you have several choices of how these display in the URL bar.  All the 'pretty' options incorporate a trailing slash, eg. `http://your_site.com/sample-post/` - normally this doesn't make any difference to how fast a page loads.  However, if you want to index into a page named 'target-post' having put an `<a id="index">Link</a>` into that page, if the link from `http://another_site.com` is of the form `<a href="http://your_site.com/target-post#index">`, Wordpress will add the trailing slash - result is the index won't work.

The way out of this is to select Custom Structure in the WP back end and `http://your_site.com/%postname%` - ie. **NO** trailing slash.  Indexed links will then work.

As far as page loading performance is concerned, looking at the logs I got a 301 (redirect) if I manually put in the URL **WITH** the slash and a 200 (success) **WITHOUT** the slash after I had made the change.  Previously (ie. letting Wordpress put in the slash), I got a 301 **WITHOUT** it a 200 **WITH** it.

So the bottom line is, in Wordpress, it doesn't matter whether the 'permalink' includes the slash or not - **UNLESS** you want to use indexed links into other pages.